# TableauSDK proxy settings

Tags: java, proxy, tableau-api

We are using TableauSDK (Java) to publish extract into Tableau Server.

Our connection to Tableau server is via proxy. So we just set the java system properties `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort`, `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`.

But it seems the proxy settings done in above java system properties does not take effect. Please help us to configure proxy settings in TableauSDK (Java)

Comment: any follow up? I also need to know because i have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tableau SDK uses a native library under the hood, which integrates with the Java SDK using JNI.

The native library respects the standard environment variables for proxy configuration, http_proxy and https_proxy.  On a Linux, or Mac system, you can simply export these environment variables:

```
export http_proxy="http://my.proxy.server:3128"
export https_proxy="http://my.proxy.server:3128"
java -jar my-application.jar
```

If you use a proxy server which requires authentication, the SDK exposes a method to set the username and password:

```
ServerAPI.initialize();
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
serverConnection.setProxyCredentials("user", "pass");
serverConnection.connect("https://tableau.url", "user", "password", "siteName");
serverConnection.publish("/path/to/extract", "projectName", "dataSourceName", true); // Overwrite Existing
```

I suspect this works pretty similarly using the Python SDK.